# How to batch remove custom labels from iOS AddressBook programmatically?

Tags: ios, addressbook

I want to batch remove custom labels from AddressBook programmatically. But there are no public API. Any one have better resolve, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean no public API? That is what the AddressBook framework is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the labels associated with the emails, phones, and addresses, you would presumably

1. Use the AddressBook.framework;
2. Get a list of the contacts (e.g. `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople`);
3. Iterate through the contacts;
4. Use `ABRecordCopyValue` to get the `ABMultiValueRef` associated with multivalue properties you're interested in (e.g., possibly `kABPersonEmailProperty`, `kABPersonAddressProperty` and/or the `kABPersonPhoneProperty`).
5. Use `ABMultiValueGetCount` to get the count of the labels;
6. Use `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex` to get the actual labels;
7. Compare those labels against `kABHomeLabel`, `kABWorkLabel`, and `kABOtherLabel`; and
8. If the label doesn't match, do whatever you want with that record's particular multivalue label.

For more information, see [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS: Direct Interaction: Programmatically Accessing the Database](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1) as well as the [Address Book Framework Reference for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212).